# Mark class/method obsolete or deprecated in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, attributes

Is there a way of marking methods/classes in C++ as obsolete?

In c# you can write:

```
[Obsolete("You shouldn't use this method anymore.")]
void foo() {}
```

I use the GNU toolchain/Eclipse CDT if that matters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way is with a `#define DEPRECATED`. On GCC, it expands to `__attribute__((deprecated))`, on Visual C++ it expands to [`__declspec(deprecated)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/044swk7y.aspx), and on compilers that do not have something silimar it expands to nothing.

Answer (score 7):

Only using compiler dependent pragmas: look up the [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html)

```
 int old_fn () __attribute__ ((deprecated));
```

Comment: This shows how to deprecate a function. Can an entire class be deprecated as well? The question hinted at this briefly, and I found this question via Google. It'd be nice to capture that here.

Answer (score 7):

The c++14 standard (or later) now provides this feature: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/deprecated

```
[[deprecated]] void F();
[[deprecated("reason")]] void G();
class [[deprecated]] H { /*...*/ };
```

Comment: The link you provided references C++14 support.

Comment: @NCheadle Fixed. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the version of C++ you are using, but Microsoft's Visual C++ has a [deprecated pragma](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8xdzzhh.aspx).  Perhaps your version has something similar.